# Why should I flag a question as a duplicate, instead of answering it?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

## Background:

I have recently begun answering more questions on Stack Overflow. I have already learned new things about programming languages I use on a daily basis and have had an overall excellent experience with answering questions.

That being said, the more questions I answer, the more I see duplicate questions, which upon some research have already been very thoroughly answered.

As I become better at answering questions, I see that for the good of the website, and to assist users, I should flag more questions as duplicates.

## Issue:

However, here in lies the crux, **as I get better at answering questions and identifying duplicates, I answer fewer questions, and flag more questions as duplicates. Therefore I answer fewer easy questions, receive less reputation, and get no thanks from the original poster.**

In other words, to play the devil's advocate, why should I flag a question as a duplicate? And as a direct consequence, do we need a mechanism to encourage flagging questions as duplicates?

## Extra details:

I want to stress that the only factor isn't reputation. When I answer a question in a way that helps someone out and they respond with 'thanks', or accept my answer, I can't deny I feel some sense of accomplishment. I don't see many people saying 'thanks' if I vote to close their question as duplicates.

I also don't feel like finding a duplicate question is a non-trivial task. Recently I saw an obvious duplicate about the JavaScript File API. It took me a few minutes to read the question, a minute to find the MDN reference page, and then 15 minutes to find a good Stack Overflow answer that describes the answer.

Comment: Ah, I did not see that other question. Even when googling the `stackexchange why should I flag a question as a duplicate` I don't see it. I believe my question raises the additional point that answering the question is more likely to receive appreciation from the original poster, which seems or merit for additional discussion.

Comment: These were the (google) search terms I used: `site:meta.stackexchange.com duplicate motivation` It wasn't the 1st hit. You have to be a bit more unspecific and creative with search terms ;-)

Comment: There are also many questions related to this on MSO, eg https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/322096/4014959 Yes, it would be wonderful if the system gave us more incentives to close dupes and to search for good dupe targets. In the mean time, we do it because it's the Right Thing, and makes the site better. Yes, it's rare for OPs to thank you for closing their question as a dupe, but it does happen. I like to write a brief comment that helps the OP understand how to apply the answers in the dupe target to their question.

Comment: I updated the title a bit. I think the `What's the incentive to flag duplicates?` question is simply too old. Things have changed since then, it was asked almost 7 years ago! I also think the `How should duplicate questions handled?` is not critical enough. That's a guide of what to do, now why it should be done. For example, if the answer to `why should I write good commit messages` doesn't include (among optimistic reasons), `they aren't anonymous so other programmer will complain, to you`, it isn't really a complete answer, and if commits were anonymous, that would be a serious problem!

Comment: Oh, I looks like this was more specific to meta.stackoverflow.com, didn't even know that existed. There is excellent discussion over there: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316564/remove-the-incentive-for-fgitw-to-answer-well-known-dupes/316652#316652 .

Comment: For me: I tend do downvote answers on obviously duplicates because the answerer showed a lack of research

Comment: Related to the 'thanks' part (will probably be deleted soon due to the strain on staff): *[Feature test: Thank you reaction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398367/feature-test-thank-you-reaction)*